# How can I make my code in compliance with MISRA 2012 RULE10.4

Tags: c, misra

```
    if(fn1())   //Line 1
     {
     a++;
     }
```

Here the return type of function fn1 is uint8_t. The function returns only values 0 or 1.

PC Lint throws error for line 1 says "Mismatched essential type categories for binary operator" [RULE 10.4 required]

Rule 10.4 says "Both operands of an operator in which the usual arithmetic conversions are performed shall have the same essential type category"

Comment: Probably `if (fn1() == 1)` will do the job.

Comment: I tried that already. But it says Mismatched essential type categories for binary operator [10.4 required]

Comment: If you've tried that, you should mention it in the question. Also show a [mcve]. It's better to _show_ your code rather than to _describe_ it.

Comment: Does changing the return type to `bool` (or `_Bool`) helps?

Comment: If you don't understand these warnings, I would strongly recommend to stop stumbling around in the dark and actually read the MISRA-C document. There's two appendix C and D which serve to educate programmers about the various dangers of the language. Also check [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Comment: MISRA is overly strict in most cases. Unless you have a hard requirement that your code should pass MISRA then I really wouldn't care about it.

Comment: If changing the function return type is not feasible, you could always check ```if ( fn() != 0 )```

Answer (score 6):

MISRA-C doesn't allow implicit checks against zero - all inputs to conditional statements must be "essentially boolean", which is what you get if you explicitly use logical operators like `==`.

In addition, MISRA-C has various rules blocking you from mixing "essenitally signed" and "essentially unsigned" in the same expression, and thereby relying on implicit type promotions. So you can't write `if (fn1() == 1)` for that reason, since `1` is a signed type and there's also a rule requiring all integer constants to have `u` suffix.

So one possible fix is `if (fn1() == 1u)`. However, since the function only returns 0 or 1, you can also cast its result to boolean type and that would be fine too: `if ((bool)fn())`. The best solution is however to rewrite the function to return `bool`, after which you can use `if(fn1())`.

Comment: Changing the return type to `bool` seems to be a good solution.

Comment: Thank you Lundin. 1u worked.     if((uint8_t) fn1() == 1u)   //Line 1

Comment: @user3340164 The cast isn't necessary.